# Font failed to load on server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, font-face

both font works locally but on server elkwood works and avenir doesn't work i got no idea why. please see image

i also tried 
font-family: "AvenirNextLTPro-Regular";
    src: url( "/fonts/AvenirNextLTPro-Regular.otf" );

[screenshot details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuOyh.png)

Comment: could you add other formats of your font to your font folder? and make all format same as each other for example .ttf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIS does not know to serve the request for `.otf` files. We need to explicitly tell IIS that these are valid file types. To do that, Add this section to your web.config under  `<system.webServer>` section.

```
<staticContent>    
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
</staticContent>
```